# Powershell : Renaming folders with formatted date

Tags: powershell, directory, rename

I have several folders which are named in the format "YYYYMMDD - Folder Name". I would like to make a powershell script to rename all those folders into the format "YYYY-MM-DD - Folder Name". I tried several scripts online to do this but couldnt get pass to split the text and format it correctly".

despite the first 8 digits being a date or not i just need to have it formated in "YYYY-MM-DD - Folder Name".  Eg: "00000000 - Folder Name 3" to "0000-00-00 - Folder Name"

Thank you in advance for the script :)[image]

Comment: The first eleven folders do not have `yyyyMmdd`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to split but to substring the foldername:

```
'yyyyMMdd'.substring(0,4) + '-' + 'yyyyMMdd'.substring(4,2) + '-' +'yyyyMMdd'.substring(6,2)
```

so for a list of subfolders inside a path...

```
foreach ($folder in (get-childitem "D:\Folders"|?{$_.PSIsContainer})){
rename-item -path $folder.fullname -newname  ($folder.basename.substring(0,4) + '-' + $folder.basename.substring(4,2) + '-' + $folder.basename.substring(6,2))
}
```

Comment: Hello Mikel, Thank you. This almost worked. But it wiped out the folder names after the date part.

Comment: The question was not very clear, I thought the folder names where only YYYYDDMM

this will replace only the first 8 characters and keep the rest of the foldername

    foreach ($folder in (get-childitem "D:\Folders"|?{$_.PSIsContainer})){
    $newname= $folder.basename -replace $folder.basename.substring(0,8), 
   ($folder.basename.substring(0,4) + '-' + $folder.basename.substring(4,2) + '-' + 
    $folder.basename.substring(6,2))
    rename-item -path $folder.fullname -newname $newname
    }

Comment: Perfect, Thank You so much for the code :) And sorry for the lack of information in my question.